# signal() : any performance impact?

Tags: c++, c, exception, signals, segmentation-fault

I need to catch `SIGABRT, SIGSEGV and SIGILL` to present the user a proper critical error message when something out of my control fails and the program need to exit.

However my program does a lot of realtime computing, so performance is important.

Does `signal()` ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/signal/ ) cause any `performance loss` (some sort of constant monitoring ?) or not at all (only triggered when an exception happen, no performance lost otherwise).

edit: My software runs on Windows (7 and higher) and OS X (10.7 and higher).

Comment: The signal handler is called when a signal is delivered, and AFAIK no modern OS uses polling for that. I'd suggest a good read into `Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment` if you need to better understand the underlying mechanisms...

Comment: The answer might heavily depend on the environmnet. So you might like to tell us the OS, compiler and other relevant stuff your program uses.

Comment: My software run on Windows (7 and higher) and OS X (10.7 and higher)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your time critical process catches signals, there is no "special" time wasting. Indeed, the kernel holds a table of signals and actions for your process which it has to walk through if a signal was send. But every way of sending a message to a process or invoking a handler needs time. A message queue or waiting on a "flag" will have nearly the same "waste".

But using signals can have other implications which should be mentioned. Nearly every system call can be interrupted if the signal arrives. The return value from the call is `EINTR`. If you have many signals you pass to your process, this may slow down your application a lot, because you have to always check for `EINTR` with go again into the system call. And every system call is a bit expensive. So looping a lot over system calls with `EINTR` return values can be a bad design.

But for your question, you only look for `SIGABRT`, `SIGSEGV` and `SIGILL`. These signals are typically only used for seldom exceptions. So don't fear to use them as needed. But avoid using these signals frequently for own IPC. That can be done but is very bad design. For user IPC there are better signal names and also better methods.

In a short: For only catching exception signals, you don't have any time critical issues here.

Comment: Great, thanks for the clear answer. For the sake of clarity I'm catching thoses exceptions for the rares cases where my program access a bugged audio or graphic driver, resulting in a crash beyond my control.

Comment: That is exact use case where it is made for :-) If you think the answer is correct, you should accept the answer :-) Thanks! ;)

Comment: @user3767622 - For what it's worth, just about every operating system is going to start processes with default signal handlers in place for SIGABRT, SIGSEGV, and SIGILL because those are by default fatal signals that result in a process exiting.  All you're doing is replacing existing signal handlers with your own.